# Integrate ts into html: uncaught ReferenceError clickbutton not defined

Tags: html, typescript, frontend

I try to build a simple CRUD frontend with **no frameworks**! I try to integrate a TypeScript file (intex.ts) into my index.html but it keeps beeing not found so that the called functions are undefined. I'm aware that browsers can't handle typescript but need javascript. I build my app before testing and all ts files get compiled. I tried integrating the compiled js file but it's not found either. All my frontend code is in directory src/public.

**How do I connect my public/index.html with my public/index.ts so that the fundtions work?**

**relevant index.html code**

```html
  <head>
    <script type="text/typescript" src="index.ts"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <button onclick="clickButton()">Click</button>
  </body>
```

**all index.ts code**

```
function clickButton() {
   document.getElementById("cases").innerText = "Hello Cases"
}
```

**error i'm getting when clicking the button**

```
index.html:18 Uncaught ReferenceError: clickButton is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:18)
```

I use express in the backend and use express.static:

```
app.use(express.static("src/public"));
```

Comment: why that? i need to define the functions don't i? and it throws errors without the function keyword

Comment: it's everything in the question : https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-94uuuu

Comment: @ Tushar Walzade: thanks, already tried that and did not help :(

Comment: where is index.ts? app.use(express.static("src/public")); will acess public folder. if your index.ts is somewhere else it wont get the file

Comment: the indes.ts is in the public folder. could be that the index.js needs to be in that folder

Comment: if compile ts on server that should be izi for you. just import index.js not ts. if you want to import ts file you need to have runtime compilers... so your app will compile ts on client side. if you have index.js just add it do your public folder and in script use this js file

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be an error caused because the function is defined outside of the global scope.
You can try to assign the function to the global **window** object just below of the function declaration:

```
function clickButton(){
   ...
}

window.clickButton = clickButton; // Now the function can be accessed from global scope
```

Also u can try to add the eventlistener on your JS file instead of using the html attribute onclick:

```
function clickButton(){
   ...
}

document.querySelector('.button-smth').addEventListener('click', clickButton);
```

This way you don't need to assign the function to the global scope at all, but you will need to add the class **'.button-smth'** (or whatever) to the html button element.

Hope this helps!

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't help because the index.ts itself is not found i guess

Answer (score 0):

Your ts need to be compiled to js first. Then, you could possibly use it as follows -

```js
function clickButton() {
   document.getElementById("cases").innerText = "Hello Cases"
}
```

```html
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="clickButton()">Click</button>
    <div id="cases"></div>
</body>
```

**Note:** This is just a possible solution

Comment: i already tried to integrate the compiled js file. the output directory is another one and the js file is not found either.

Comment: So, you'll need to provide the relative path of your js file